# Find height of class and apply to another class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I've been looking around the web for an answer for a couple of hours and cannot find anything so I'm hoping someone can help me.

I want to take the height of a wrapper div who's class is `movie` and apply it to an inner div who's class is `movie-center`. How can I do this using JS or jQuery?

I am a newbie when it comes to JS, so I would really appreciate if you could lay everything out for me (including any HTML needed).

Thank you!

**EDIT 1:** Maybe if I am explaining what I am doing people will have a better understanding. I am making a responsive WordPress theme. As the width of the browser is smaller, the movie widths are smaller. I want the overlay title and graphic to stay in the center. I tried doing this with CSS and it cannot be done fully unless I know the exact height (which I won't because of resizing).

**EDIT 2:** here is the browser's rendered html code:

```
<article id="movie-97" class="post-97 movie type-movie status-publish hentry"><a href="http://localhost:8888/movies/hard-truth-levity-hope">

<div class="movie-center">

    <div class="movie-overlay">

        <div class="movie-play"></div>

        <h2 class="movie-title">Hard Truth, Levity and Hope</h2>

    </div> <!-- end .movie-overlay -->

</div> <!-- end .movie-center -->

<div class="movie-thumb"><img width="480" height="270" src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/truth-levity-hope.jpg" class="attachment-movie-thumb wp-post-image" alt="Hard Truth, Levity and Hope" /></div>
```

**EDIT 3:** [Here's a Pastebin for my website](http://pastebin.com/DVX104A0). Note: it has been stripped down to only show the essential parts of the site.

Comment: can you post your html code?

Comment: why with JS? This can be done better with CSS

Comment: @emilioicai he may have varying elements with the `movie` class on lots of pages, which all have different heights, and wants to dynamically set the height of elements with the `movie-center` class. I agree, there are easier ways to do this though.

Comment: html/php code is posted. And I cannot get what I want with CSS.

Comment: Will there be multiple .movie articles on each page?

Comment: @brianrhea yes. I just edited my post again with more info.

Comment: Give us HTML from browser source. Right now there is no `.movie` class in your HTML!

Comment: Is the problem that it doesn't work when you resize the window? If so, that would be because the heights are already set--you need to listen for the window resize event to recalculate heights.

Comment: Problem is most probably in no `.movie` class:)

Comment: Post has been updated with html code :)

Comment: I have updated the post again and included a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/DVX104A0

Answer (score 1):

What you've done is the correct way. Make sure you've loaded jQuery properly and try to wrap your code inside DOM ready handler `$(document).ready(function() {...});` or shorter form `$(function() {...});`

```
$(function() {
    $('.movie').each(function() {
        var h = $(this).height();
        $(this).find('.movie-center').height(h);
    });   
});
```

---

Edit: Since you're using Wordpress, there's probably a conflict happen here, try to use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('window').resize(function() {
        $('.movie').each(function() {
            var h = $(this).height();
            $(this).find('.movie-center').height(h);
        });  
    }).resize();
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "wrap your code inside DOM...". I copied/pasted your code and it's not working for some reason.

Comment: This actually is returning a value, but not the correct one. It's saying the height is 18px. Not sure why. The "unaltered height" is 270px (the height before being resized). So it should be saying 270px.

Comment: If it's return a height, but the height is wrong then my guess is you need to clear a float on `.movie`

Comment: It is not returning a height for some reason.

Comment: @Connor: Check if your `.movie` class have some `float` set with your Web Developer Tool, keep in mind that JS doesn't calculate the element height as it would be a ruler, it just take the DOM element height ;)

Comment: @TomSarduy yes I have `.movie` float left. I removed the float temporarily but hasn't fixed it. I can't figure out why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
 /* Get height of .movie thumb preview */
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                  $('.movie').each(function() {
                    var h = $(this).height();
                    console.log(h);
                    $(this).find('.movie-center').first().css('height',h);
                      console.log($(this).find('.movie-center').first().height())
                  });
                });
```

Comment: Neither are working for me. I have updated my question with more information.

Comment: Please check the above code . I think it should work .

Comment: @yanktrakaar no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Connor,

This will get you what you're looking for:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.movie').each(function() {
    var h = $(this).height();
    $(this).find('.movie-center').height(h);
  });
});
```

A quick explanation. You'll notice that jQuery's .height() function is called twice. First, without any params and then with `h` passed in.

Pull up your JS console (`cmd+opt+j` if you're using Chrome) to see how this actually works.

The question at the top of this page has an id of `#question-header`, so if you enter this in the console `$('#question-header').height()` you'll see that it returns 36. That's because that element is 36 pixels tall.

So, calling `.height` without any params will return the height of the selected element. But, we can set the height by passing in a number. Try this by pasting this in to the JS console:

`$('#question-header').height(1000)`

The header is now 1000px tall!

The third line of the code basically says, "Hey, within `this` particular instance of the `.movie` article, find the `.movie-center` element and set the height.

So, there you go. Some working code and hopefully an explanation as to exactly why/how to use it in the future.

Comment: Guys why you're saving height to variable which is used only once, but not wrapped `this` used twice??

This should be: 
`$('.movie').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.find('.movie-center').height($this.height());
});`

Comment: Brian, thanks for the very helpful explanation but your code is not working :(

Comment: @MaciejPyszyński Fair enough, that'll work just fine. Personally, I find `.height(h)` to be more readable than `.height($this.height());`. But it's just a personal preference.

Comment: @Connor, I assume you're dead certain that `<?php post_class(); ?>` is outputting `movie`? If you add this: `console.log(h);` immediately after the `var h = ...` line, what do you see in your console?

Comment: @brianrhea the console says 270

Comment: Ok, the good news then is that we know jQuery is loaded and that's all good. Hopefully this confirms some things for @Felix's solution as well. It would seem to me then that the code is firing. Are you certain then that what you're trying to do (resize .movie-center to the same height as .movie) is really what you want?

Comment: To confirm that this code is firing and you're targeting the right elements, change `var h = $(this).height();` to `var h = $(this).height() * 10;` and you should see that .movie-center is way too tall. If that happens, then we've confirmed that we're getting the right data and targeting the right elements.

Comment: Just want to point out that `.movie-thumb` is a sibling, not a child of `.movie-center`. Are you expecting that the contents of `.movie-thumb` would be affected by this resizing that we're attempting? If so, you need to restructure your HTML.

Comment: Here's a pastebin for my site. Hopefully this helps. http://pastebin.com/DVX104A0

Comment: @brianrhea just saw your comments now. My css for `.movie` is `width: 50%; height: auto; max-width: 480px; max-height: 270px; float: left;`. I know that `.movie-center` is a sibling of `.movie-thumb`. `.movie-thumb` resizes based on `.movie`.

Comment: @Connor try removing `max-height: 270px;` from your css and that may very well do it.

Comment: No luck unfortunately :(

Comment: Sorry, Connor. No idea then. If you get the site in to a production state, I could take a look. There must be something else going on.

Comment: @brianrhea I've decided that I'm going to recode the page and check the JS along the way. I'll let you know if I get it to work. Thank you!

Comment: @brianrhea I just rewrote all the code and still couldn't get it to work (in Safari). So, I decided to try your console test in Chrome to see what the browser was returning. It said 270 (the correct number). Then I looked up at my site and noticed it actually applied it! Why would it work in Chrome but not Safari? Both are webkit. Thanks!

Comment: Connor, there could be a hundred things going on at this point because we know now that the code is actually correct. Without being in your environment with your codebase, it's next to impossible to debug. If I were you, I would log every variable in that block to the console and view the output in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and IE. Go through it with a fine-toothed comb, be thorough and find out exactly where the expected action is failing and in which browser(s) is it failing.